# Combining Google Analytics outbound clicks and Javascript "speed bump"

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have implemented the correct universal GA for outbound click tracking, but I've also implemented one of those "speed bump" pop-up messages that fires when someone clicks an offsite link, using the below javascript. (bank client - requires speed bump)

Will this "break" the GA outbound click tracking in any way? (Person clicking sees a modal box pop up with disclaimer and a "Continue" or "Decline" button choice.)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.external').click(function() {
var link = $(this).attr('href');

$('<div>By accessing this link you will be leaving the site...</div>').dialog({
  title: "Third-Party Site Disclaimer",
  modal : true,
  overlay: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    opacity: 1
  },
  buttons: {
    'Continue': function() {
      $(this).dialog('close').remove();
      window.open(link);
    },
    'Decline': function() {
      $(this).dialog('close').remove();
      return false;
    }
  }
});

return false;
});
});
```

Google's outbound click tracking code I have in there:

```
<script>
    /**
    * Function that tracks a click on an outbound link in Analytics.
    * This function takes a valid URL string as an argument, and uses that URL string
    * as the event label. Setting the transport method to 'beacon' lets the hit be sent
    * using 'navigator.sendBeacon' in browser that support it.
    */
    var trackOutboundLink = function(url) {
       ga('send', 'event', 'outbound', 'click', url, {
         'transport': 'beacon',
         'hitCallback': function(){document.location = url;}
       });
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Did you test it yourself?

Comment: Could you provide the method you used for outbound link tracking? My guess is that is now only tracking the "intent" to leave... You'd need to add an event send inside the 'Continue' and 'Decline' functions of this modal for the more explicit user action.

Comment: I added the outbound click code above. Thank you all - this is beyond me.

Comment: And, by the way, the speed bump code is firing the modal window, but then the link fires and goes to the destination page, without giving the user the ability to choose Continue or Decline. It's as if the window.open(link) line in the speedbump.js is getting hijacked.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing how you set up the outbound link tracking, here's where I would place the GA events in your provided code (along with how I would name the category, action, and label for each).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.external').click(function() {
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    ga('send', 'event', 'Outbound Link', 'Intent', link);

    $('<div>By accessing this link you will be leaving the site...</div>').dialog({
      title: "Third-Party Site Disclaimer",
      modal : true,
      overlay: {
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        opacity: 1
      },
      buttons: {
        'Continue': function() {
          ga('send', 'event', 'Outbound Link', 'Disclaimer Continue', link);
          $(this).dialog('close').remove();
          window.open(link);
        },
        'Decline': function() {
          ga('send', 'event', 'Outbound Link', 'Disclaimer Decline', link);
          $(this).dialog('close').remove();
          return false;
        }
      }
    });

    return false;
    });
});
```

You would now be tracking outbound link intent and then tracking continue/decline as separate actions.

Comment: Thank you very much - I just added the outbound tracking code from Google - does your answer above still work? I very much appreciate the assistance.

Comment: Are you referring to Google's autotrack.js? Your jQuery listener is looking for an ```.external``` class on an ```<a>``` tag, so somehow that is being added to the tags- if that is correctly working, then the above code would work fine.

Comment: Thank you very much - I've been testing that code and I believe it's working. Appreciate the help!